# Spring-MVC: Controller method isn't called at request

Tags: spring-mvc, osgi

I can't get my controller involved when the request is fired. I see the site but I can't see the message attribute "Hello World!". The whole thing is in a osgi-environment (virgo).

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/metamodel")
public class FirstController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FirstController.class);

    public FirstController() {
        LOG.info("------------ FirstController ------");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void helloWorld(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I can see the log, so the controller is there.

views.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition extends="default" name="metamodel/list">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/metamodel/list.jspx" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

webmvc-config.xml

```
    <mvc:view-controller path="/metamodel" view-name="metamodel/list" />
```

list.jspx

```
<div xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"     xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <h3><c:out value="${message}" /></h3>

</div>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you put the whole code? It will help to see what is missing in configurations? Definitely you do not need to define "<mvc:view-controller path="/metamodel" view-name="metamodel/list" />" this in config file. If i have a the code i\anyone can run it locally and suggest a fix. Good luck.

Comment: Yes full spring context file would help (web.xml seems fine, as `<mvc:view-controller>` worked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing this:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/metamodel" view-name="metamodel/list" />
```

And change your controller method to return view name like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String helloWorld(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World!");
    return "list";
}
```

See [16.14.4 Configuring View Controllers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-view-controller) - `mvc:view-controller` should be used to create *bridge* controllers which just forward requests to views without any logic (which include adding model attributes).

Comment: `/metamodel` may be added to logical view name, so return `"list"`

Comment: I tried the return value "list" and metamodel/list" but still no success. Also added a log statement which is never in the log

Comment: Found it. This was missing: <mvc:annotation-driven />